# WHMCS there was an error in Domain WHOIS Lookup

Tags: whmcs

Yesterday,i have tried the Domain WHOIS Lookup in the WHMCS but when i entered a domain name i got this error "There was a problem connecting to the domain registry. Please check port 43 is open in your servers firewall?"

Comment: When i sent a ticket to my web hosting they replied by "We do apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately this is something we cannot due where our hosting is on a shared hosting environment."

Comment: how can i workarround this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your hosting provider do not want to open port 43 in the hosting firewall. If that's the case i'm afraid you have to move to another hosting provider.